# ODE with $\alpha\in \mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, complex-numbers

What about the classical methods for solve ODE's when appear complex coefficients? How can we deal with the following ODE:

$$\ddot x(t) - \alpha x(t)=0,$$

where $\alpha\in \mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$ and $x:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{C}$ ?.

Comment: If $x$ is supposed to be $\Bbb C\to\Bbb C$, then a differentiable function $\Bbb C\to \Bbb C$ is analytic at all points, therefore you obtain a linear condition on the coefficients of its Taylor expansion.

Comment: If it's supposed to be $\Bbb R\to \Bbb C$, then given the obvious coordinates this would be undistinguishable from an ODE $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: @Gae.S  Now the question is in a more clear form.

Comment: @JeanMarie  Now the question is in a more clear form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write

$$x(t)=y(t)+i z(t) \ \ \text{and} \ \ \alpha=a+ib \tag{1}$$

where $x$ and $y$ are real-valued functions.

Plug (1) into your initial ODE ; separate real and imaginary parts, giving:

$$\begin{cases}\ddot y(t) = a y(t) - b z(t)\\
\ddot z(t) = b y(t) + a z(t)\end{cases}$$

Then follow the classical procedure (bringing back to a first degree system) as described for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1547351).

Comment: Dear professor,

what happen if $x(t):\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ ? Could a solution  take the form $x(t)=c_1 e^{\lambda_1 t} + c_2 e^{\lambda_2 t}$ ?

Comment: In this case, it means $z(t)=0$ , consequently, the second differential equation reduces to $0=by(t)+a0$, therefore (**unless $b=0$...**), $y(t)=0$ ; therefore $x(t)=y(t)+iz(t)=0+i0=0$.